# Replicate title of document library

Tags: javascript, document-library

So I am trying to hide the title of my webpart, and then display the same title, but with the title now being a link. Is there an easy way to do this using javascript? The difficulty in this lies in the fact that the web part i am trying to make the title a link is inside of a hillbillytabs tabbed web part. So, I can't just turn the chrome to none as the tabs wouldn't find the web part then. Anyone see a workaround? I would honestly be happy with hiding the title, and then putting an anchor tag in its place and using inline CSS to change it, however I am not sure on how that would be done either.

Edit: apologies guys, I should have been more specific. Here is the set up, it is a hillbillytab that contains a content editor. The content editor has some javascript that pulls up a document library's url based off of the parameter I send to the page. What I would like to do, is take "Project documents" and make it a link to the document library itself, not just an iframe with a view of the document library.[image]

Comment: are you mean you need to show title of web part without link ?!

Comment: You've tagged this with `document-library` - are the web parts you are using List View web parts that are for libraries?  If so, the titles should be links by default.  Is the hillbilly tabs script removing the links?

Comment: Is Project documents title is Content Editor or related to hillbillytabs tabbed web part ?

Comment: it is the content editor title

Answer (score 1):

To Disable the Clickable Title URL of Library WebPart in SharePoint

- Edit the page > Edit the web part > at advanced > `Title URL` > replace the current URL with `#`

Ref : https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/20/disable-the-clickable-title-url-of-list-viewer-webpart-in-sharepoint/

**[Update]**

Regarding your question update , you can make title linkable to document library With the same method

Edit the page > Edit the contetn editor web part > at advanced > `Title URL` > set the URL of your document library.

[image]

Comment: This works great, but, there are 2 limitations... The title url will only allow me to append after /sites/site1/sitePages... AND if I want to change the doclib link based on the passed in parameter, i believe i need to do it with JS so it is dynamic